# Show a Customized Power Point Slide on browser

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web, powerpoint

I have this page on my Web app, I want to get all the values from here and make Powerpoint slides, so staff can download and view. How can I make a Customized PowerPoint on a browser?
[image: Page of my webApp]

Comment: What's the benefit of it being a PowerPoint presentation? Could it be a series of slides in a web page? What server-side framework are you using? How do you envisage the selection of slides would work? Please update your question with answers.

Comment: Using Office.js and PowerPoint Online, that would be possible. The learning curve is steep. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office

Answer (score 0):

[Prezi](https://prezi.com/) is my personal favorite.

There is an open source implementations:

1. [impress.js](https://impress.js.org/#/bored)
2. [revealjs](https://revealjs.com/)